# SQLDependency and sql server restart error instead of restart notification

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using `SqlDependency` to be notified of changes to a database.  Everything is working great, I get notified when Insert operations are happening but when SQL server is restarted I receive an `SqlNotificationEventArgs` that contains:

- Type = Change
- Source = Client
- Info = Error

From the documentation for [SqlNotificationSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationsource.aspx) and [SqlNoticationInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I was expecting a notification event that contains:

- Type = Change
- Source = System
- Info = Restart

I am not sure where to be looking for why it is sending the wrong information.